Setting an Excel header or footer using office-js
I'm trying to write a generic function which changes a header or footer in Excel. I am using ScriptLab. This is the code I tried:
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const typeOfHeader = "defaultForAllPages.centerFooter";
    let headers = sheet.pageLayout.headersFooters;
    headers[typeOfHeader] = "My New Text For Header";
    await context.sync();
  });
}

Script lab runs this code without errors, but yet the centerFooter does not change.
I am using a string variable named typeOfHeader on purpose, as I want to keep my code generic. Given typeOfHeader and the headers object, how can I change the defaultForAllPages.centerFooter ?

Is there really no-one with an answer here? Anyone?
